# Is python secure than wordpress?

Tags: php, python, wordpress

I am planning to develop a E-commerce website. i was thinking to use Wordpress CMS so that there will be plugins available for implementing the E-commerce feature. but questions was raised about the security of wordpress. i have got few suggestions from by friends about developing site in python.

Can anyone please help me with the advantages of python over wordpress. is it a good idea to build website in python than wordpress?

Comment: Python is a language where wordpress is a framework. Wordpress sits on top of PHP.

Comment: If you're asking whether PHP is more secure than python then it all depends on the competence of the programmer -the language doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thanks Lix. So which language will be easy to develop and less time consuming?

Comment: that would be python!

Comment: `"...easy to develop and less time consuming?"` - That question is really too broad to be answered in this format. It really depends.

Comment: @praveen - Is that statement based on something other than your personal preference?

Comment: @Lix: yes I have used PHP and python both to develop web apps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't really have a clear answer, because you're not comparing apples to apples here.

Wordpress is a Content Management System (CMS), a piece of software built using the php language.

Python is simply a language.

Vulnerabilities have certainly been found in Wordpress before, it's true. Similarly, software developed in Python can have vulnerabilities.

If your real question is "Would it be better securitywise for me to develop an entirely new CMS in Python, or use Wordpress?" then my answer is that you should almost certainly use Wordpress. If you're asking the question, you probably wouldn't be able to do better than the community of Wordpress developers at security - I know I couldn't.

Comment: Somehow you managed to save this question by providing a great answer. +1!